# alinear listas html

Tags: html, css

estoy creando tres listas que se posicionan una al lado de otra, el problema se presenta cuando el contenido de las lista no tiene la misma cantidad de elementos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede apreciar en la imagen, la tercera lista tiene un titulo y dos elementos lo que me gustaría conseguir es alinear las listas.

aquí el html

```
<div class="contenedormenu">
    <ul>
        <p>Materiales de construcción</p>
        <li>Madera</li>
        <li>Cemento</li>
        <li>Fierros</li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
        <p>Herramientas</p>
        <li>Electricas</li>            
        <li>Herramientas de construccion</li>
        <li>Herramientas de jardin</li>       
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <p>Herramientas</p>
        <li>Electricas</li>
        <li>Ejemplo</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

css

```
.contenedormenu{
 width: 100%;
 height: 40%;
 background-color: grey;
 color: white
 }
.contenedormenu ul{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alcanzaría con que:

- A la clase `contenedormenu` le apliques una disposición flexible para que sus hijos sean cajas flexibles
- Por cierto no considero que el título de cada una de tus listas deba formar parte del cuerpo del `ul` es decir no es un elemento de la lista en si
- Puedes envolver cada una de las listas en un `div` nuevo darle una clase y así posteriormente incluso te será mas fácil maquetarlos

Propuesta

```html
    <style>
      .contenedormenu {
        display: flex;
      }
      .listado {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="contenedormenu">
      <div class="listado">
          <p>Materiales de construcción</p>
          <ul>
              <li>Madera</li>
              <li>Cemento</li>
              <li>Fierros</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="listado">
         <p>Herramientas</p>
         <ul>
            <li>Electricas</li>            
            <li>Herramientas de construccion</li>
            <li>Herramientas de jardin</li>       
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="listado">
        <p>Herramientas</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Electricas</li>
            <li>Ejemplo</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Con una salida así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo del borde es opcional

Answer (score 0):

El problema que presentas es por la forma que diseñas los datos, en efecto se baja debido a falta de un dato extra para alinearse al resto, ya que los datos se están apilando hacia abajo (aparte de que

por defecto es "display: block" haciendo que el siguiente elemento se apile hacia abajo), lo que puedes hacer es colocar "vertical-align: top" en ".contenedormenu ul".

Por otro lado:
Disculpa, pero no es mas eficiente usar  ?  así se ajustan y aparte podrías editar a gusto el alineamiento de cada uno

```css
 table{
      border: 1px solid black
    }
    th{
      border: 1px solid black
    }
    td{
      border: 1px solid black
    }
```

```html
 <div>
      <table style="width:50%">
        <tr>
          <th>Materiales de construcción</th>
          <th>Herramientas</th>
          <th>Herramientas</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda :)